# How to keep a button in access form disabled after one click using VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, vba

I am trying to code a button that allows user to only click once. I have managed to disable the button after one click but when I reopen the form the button is still enabled.

How can I keep the button disabled after one click. Ultimately I want to make ACCDE containing a form that has a button which is only enabled once. the ACCDE file will be used to for different projects and every time when starting a new project a copy of the generic ACCDE file will be used. The button needs to be internally enabled for every time you start a new project (i.e open a generic copy of the ACCDE) and becomes disabled after the user has clicked on it and remain disable forever for that particular project.

I managed to do the following coding for that button.

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Reset AutoCounter"
Command21.Enabled = False
Command25.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The code above disables the button after one click, but when you close the form and reopen it the button comes as enabled.

Is there a code that I can use to keep the button disabled.

Comment: You will have to store the information in the Projects table and set Enabled at runtime, e.g. in `OnCurrent`.

Comment: Hi Andre, could you please elaborate. I am new to access vba.

Comment: Instead of 'storing' the value in a variable in memory, you need to store it in your datasource.  you need another column, either in a new table or an existing one with only one row, that stores whether or not your button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *TempVars* for this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open()

    If IsNull(TempVars("ProjectEnabled").Value) Then
        ' Initialise.
        TempVars.Add "ProjectEnabled", True
    End If
    Me!Command21.Enabled = TempVars("ProjectEnabled").Value

End Sub

Private Sub Command21_Click()

    Command25.SetFocus
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Reset AutoCounter"
    Command21.Enabled = False
    TempVars "ProjectEnabled", False

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Testing shows, that the above doesn't work as TempVars are not persistent.

So the simple workaround is to create a small local table with a Boolean field with *DefaultValue* of *True*, and then update this to *False* when clicking the button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but can you explain me what do you mean by "ProjectEnabled". P.S the code docen't work on line 3 "TempVars "ProjectEnabled", True"

Comment: It's just a name for this stored variable - could be anything. And forgot the _Add_ method, sorry. See edit please.

Comment: Thank you. This worked as I wanted but only slight issue is that the button becomes enabled when you close the database and reopen it. TempVars works perfectly fine when you have the access programme open in the back ground but when you close it and reopen it the button becomes enable.

Comment: It seems you are right. I don't use TempVars but thought they where persistent, but they are not; when you close the application, all TempVars go poof. So you may have to either create a property or (simpler) use a local table. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

you either do it at *design time*:

- in VBA IDE select the wanted `UserForm` from *Project View* and have it appear in the main code pane
- select its `Command21` control
- in `Properties` View (F4 to pop it out) set its `Enabled` property to `False`

or, do it at *runtime*

- insert this in your `UserForm` code pane :

  ```
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      Command21.Enabled = False
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Both method disables the button permanently without clicking. I want the button to be disabled permanently after one click. the button should still be disabled once you close the form and reopen it.

Comment: just to point out that both methods don't _"disable the button permanently"_ since they just disable it and any other code can re-enable it at any time. Anyhow I understand I didn't catch your real need. Sorry for that. Hope somebody else will help you.

Comment: Using the code above the button will be disabled permanently in ACCDE and you cant change the code or change the design in ACCDE.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: I don't even know what ACCDE is. My fault I didn't ask you before answering and spare me the downvote...

Answer (score -1):

Create a local table and make it hidden.
Use a value from that table to determine whether to <del>hide</del> enable it or not on either form load or application load (using a global variable).